# Installing Pilot Assy in Majestic DVR33 P

Tags: repair, fireplace, installation, propane, pilot-light

A couple of years ago I had a repair person take a look at my Majestic fireplace because it was shutting off after a couple of minutes.  His opinion was that something in the exhaust was being blocked and wanted to sell me a new unit, which I still cannot afford.  Recently I took a look at it and as near as I can tell there is nothing blocking the venting of it, but I also saw that he had removed my pilot assembly! Of course I have no idea who he was now so I purchased a replacement assembly online but I can't work out how it gets installed since the old one is missing.  There is also a loose bracket that is apparently part of it but it's not obvious how it fits in.  So if anyone can help esp with a picture of how it's supposed to look I would appreciate it!  [image]